# How to unlock terrafrom state file in S3 bucket and lock id in dynamodb by makefile commands?

Tags: amazon-web-services, git, github, makefile, terraform-provider-aws

[Please refer the git bash image for more clear on the error i face.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Fx9T.png) I am using makefile to deploy,plan,init. But I am not sure how to use the make file commands for unlocking state file using git bash.My terrafrom state file is in S3 bucket and the lock id is in dynamodb

I tried Terraform force-unlock .But it didnt worked

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier if you shared your terraform error by attaching a picture or via a link, but anyway I understand that currently you have your terraform state locked.

To unlock your terraform state run the following command:

```bash
terraform force-unlock <lock-id> -force
```

For those cases, when you plan or apply, you get the error of terraform state locked, in that output you should see the lock id of that lock, then run `force-unlock` with this lock id to unlock it.

Comment: I attached the image. https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Fx9T.png

Comment: Have you tried running with the `-force` flag ?

Comment: Thanks for uploading the image, this looks like a standard terraform state lock error, but when you try to unlock the state you get another error indicating it was not unlocked by another process.

I think it's because you have another terraform process running when you try to unlock the terraform state, try running `ps -aux | grep "terraform"` for linux or open task manager for windows and kill terraform background processes and run `force-unlock` again.

Comment: yes i tried with -force flag. It didn't worked. In task manager there is no terraform processes available